# Check connection state - C++ odbc driver for Ignite

Tags: c++, odbc, ignite

I am using Apache Ignite driver for ODBC in order to query my cache(my application is wrriten in C++).

As part of implementing it I need a way to know if a connection is still open in order to use it.

I know that for Windows API the solution is to use this

```
SQLGetConnectAttr(dbc, SQL_COPT_SS_CONNECTION_DEAD,...)
```

But AFAIK I can't call it with ignite driver API.

Is there any other standrad way to check current conncetion state?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_DEAD` is supported by Ignite and should work. Here is the [actual page](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/specification#section-connection-attribute-conformance). But make sure that this is what you want because the `SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_DEAD` checks the most recent state of the connection, and might not be the current connection state.

Also, pay attention that since 2.5 Ignite's ODBC driver supports [failover 
mechanism](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7811) and tries to automatically restore connection, once the current server node is down.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it would not be possible with ODBC. Most attributes are not supported
https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.1/docs/conformance

You should use the ignite C++ instead. If you already built your project, then you might have a lot of refactoring
https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/docs/getting-started

Good luck

Comment: The problem is that Ignite C++ creates a new node which comes with a big overhead. I need to use it for my native code only as thin client, which is currently supported only in Java and C#.Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do a simple check like next or similar:

```
    SQLCHAR req[] = "SELECT 1";

    SQLRETURN ret = SQLExecDirect(stmt, req, SQL_NTS);

    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret))
        //conection failed
```

It should work with Ignite to check the connection.